# Doctrine2 cannot access JoinColumn in QueryBuilder Query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some rather simple Entities, on of the is A, A has column `parent` annotated with

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentid", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist"})
```

Which is basically a reference to another A entity.

When I try to query this Entity A.parent in a query like this

```
$qb->select("A.parent")
// or
$qb->select("A.parentid")
// or
$qb->select("A.Parent")
$qb->leftJoin("A.parent", "parent")
```

I end up getting this error:

> Entity .... has no field or association named parent/parentid

Answer (score 1):

If the definition is something like this

```
/**
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentid", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $parentField;
```

The query builder should be like this

```
$qb
->select('a, p')
->from('AppBlogBundle:A', 'a')
->leftJoin('a.parentField','p');
```